# C++ WinApi - Send a click from parent window to all child window, at the same position

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm currently using the Windows API to create a Sub-Window (with CreateWindowEx) and overlay it like a popup. I'm making it so the windows are always set to the exact same size and position (you change one, it changes the other), so they should always match. I want it so when one window is clicked, it passes it to the other window.

So if you click on an element on window A, it will do what ever it bound it it, then pass it to Window B afterwards. Sorry if this question is poorly worded, it's hard to describe.

Comment: two ideas: `SendInput` or it might work to just add message handlers that do not mark the message as consumed / handled.

Comment: @dav: `SendInput` sends input which is received by the foreground window. If you received user input, you *are* the foreground window. Sending that input again doesn't send it anywhere else. Apart from that, you cannot *"mark the message as consumed"* in the Windows API. Likewise, you cannot mark it as not consumed.

Comment: @IInspectable "*Sending that input again doesn't send it anywhere else*" - it does if you specify a different location for the input to be delivered to.  So, when windows A gets input, determine the offset of that input within the window, then loop through the other windows sending new input to offsets that are relative to each window

Comment: @rem: `SendInput` doesn't have a parameter to specify a recipient. Am I missing something or is it you?

Comment: @IInspectable The input in this situation is mouse clicks, which carry target coordinates in them.  So you can create new mouse inputs that have specific coordinates in them.  Though, in this situation, I really wouldn't use `SendInput()` for this, I would just have the recipient window send messages directly to the other windows as needed.

Comment: Handle `WM_NCHITTEST` for the top window and return `HTTRANSPARENT`, and clicks will go through to what's underneath.

Comment: @rem: The input here is supposed to go to the *same* coordinates, just to the window underneath. `SendInput` doesn't help with that. Your alternative suggestion doesn't work either: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903).

Comment: @IInspectable my understanding was that the OP was creating multiple windows side-by-side, not stacked. If stacked, then my suggestion to use `SendInput()` won't work, but my suggestion to send messages directly would. Jonathan's suggestion has some merit, though it would prevent standard click messages from being generated, so would require more work.